# GlideAjax request doesn't return any response

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I'm newer in servicenow developing.
I try to create a bundle "Script Include" - "Client Script".
Using background script I see, that my script include works fine. 
But when I try to call this include via client script, it doesn't return any response.

Here is my method in Script Include:

```
usersCounter: function () {
        var gr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
        gr.query();
        var users = gr.getRowCount();
        gs.info('Number of users'+ ' ' + users);
        return users;
```

And here is my client script:

```
var ga = new GlideAjax('SCI_Training_ScriptIncludeOnChange');
       ga.addParam('sysparm_name', 'usersCounter');
       ga.getXML(getUsers);

       function getUsers(response)  {
           var numberOfUsers = response.responseXML.documentElement.getAttribute("answer");
           g_form.clearValue('description');
           console.log(numberOfUsers);
```

And I have null in my console.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of why it's not working, you probably want to change your server side GlideRecord to use GlideAggregate instead, and just let mysql return the row count:

```
var gr = new GlideAggregate('sys_user');
gr.addAggregate('COUNT');
gr.query();
gr.next();
var users = gr.getAggregate('COUNT');
gs.info('Number of users'+ ' ' + users);
return users;
```

Doing a GlideRecord#query with no where clause is essentially doing a "SELECT * FROM sys_user", bringing over all the data, when all you're asking for is the row count from the metadata in the result set.

Beyond that, make sure your Script Include properly extends `AbstractAjaxProcessor` and has the `client-callable` field set to `true` per this:
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/script/server_scripting/reference/r_ExamplesOfAsynchronousGlideAjax.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug your `getUsers()` method. Try to check what the object structure of `response` is.

You could also use

```
var ga = new GlideAjax('SCI_Training_ScriptIncludeOnChange');
ga.addParam('sysparm_name', 'usersCounter');
ga.getXMLAnswer(getUsers);

function getUsers(response)  {
  var numberOfUsers = response;
  g_form.clearValue('description');
  console.log(numberOfUsers);
}
```